# Getting Caused by: android.os.FileUriExposedException: after performing required steps

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-camera, android-fileprovider

I have followed a couple of articles regarding `FileUriExposedException` issue and how to fix it. I followed one of them, and did following, but after all of this i am still getting following error message.

> Caused by: android.os.FileUriExposedException:
>   file:///storage/emulated/0/My_photo_1518346135450 exposed beyond app
>   through ClipData.Item.getUri()

This is what i have done so far

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
   <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>

    </provider>
```

**provider_paths.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path path="."   name="app_cam_images" />
</paths>
```

and this is what i do in my activity, before launching the camera.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
    randomString= String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
    FILE_NAME= FILE_NAME+randomString;
    File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), FILE_NAME);


    String authorities = getApplicationContext().getPackageName()+ ".fileprovider";
    Uri imageURI= FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, authorities, photo);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,imageURI);
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this before `startActivityForResult` you have to grant the flag for reading the URI..

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
```